# Where to download Earnings Conference Call transcripts?

Tags: earnings

Is there any places (like EDGAR) that I can download Earnings Conference Call transcripts in bulk? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can download from Refinitiv in bulk after paying them `$15k - $20k`.

CapitalIQ, FactSet and Investext all have an upper limit of 10 to 50 documents per download.